# Java - String can be split with regex but regex match returns false

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to split the following string with the following as example:
`Team A 2-3 Team B`
It is a string with the team's names on 2 sides and the score between them in the middle. I need to obtain the team's names and scores respectively. This is my code so far for this part:

```
    String homeTeam;
    String awayTeam;
    int homeGoal = 0;
    int awayGoal = 0;
    String input = "Team A 2-3 Team B";
    Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("-");
    String[] teamNames = input.split(" (\\d+)-(\\d+) ");
    homeTeam = teamNames[0];
    awayTeam = teamNames[1];
    for(int i = 0; i < teamNames.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(teamNames[i]);
    }
    s.findInLine("(\\d+)-(\\d+)");
    MatchResult result = s.match();
    for (int i=1; i<=result.groupCount(); i++)
    System.out.println(result.group(i));
    s.close();
```

The output for this:

```
Team A
Team B
2
3
```

as it should be.

However, since there is another case where the match has yet to be played `Team A  Team B`. The 2 team names in this case are separated by 2 spaces. The regex used above no longer works so I have 2 cases. This is my overall code:

```
        String homeTeam;
        String awayTeam;
        int homeGoal = 0;
        int awayGoal = 0;
        String input = "Team A 2-3 Team B";
        Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("-");

    boolean b = Pattern.matches(" (\\d+)-(\\d+) ", input);
    if (b){
        String[] teamNames = input.split(" (\\d+)-(\\d+) ");
        homeTeam = teamNames[0];
        awayTeam = teamNames[1];
        for(int i = 0; i < teamNames.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(teamNames[i]);
        }
        s.findInLine("(\\d+)-(\\d+)");
        MatchResult result = s.match();
        for (int i=1; i<=result.groupCount(); i++)
            System.out.println(result.group(i));
        s.close();
    } else {
        String[] teamNames = input.split("  ");
        homeTeam = teamNames[0];
        awayTeam = teamNames[1];
        for(int i = 0; i < teamNames.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(teamNames[i]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(b);
```

The problem that I am getting is that b is returning false even for the string

```
Team A 2-3 Team B
```

And so only the else case is returned with this code.

I tested both parts individually with strings that match their own pattern and they worked fine but not when I combine then like this.

Comment: The whole String has to match. Try adding ".*" at start and end of the pattern.

Comment: `matches` will compare the pattern against the full string, and of course they don't match; use `find` instead

Comment: Let's say
New York Yankees 4-5 Chicago Cubs
I would like to obtain
New York Yankees
Chicago Cubs
4
5 
so that I could put them into variables

Comment: `([\w ]*?)\s+(?:(\d+)-(\d+))?\s+([\w ]*)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/f6F3wQ/2)

```
([\w ]*?)\s+(?:(\d+)-(\d+))?\s+([\w ]*)
```

#### Code

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/zliJY0)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        final String regex = "([\\w ]*?)\\s+(?:(\\d+)-(\\d+))?\\s+([\\w ]*)";
        final String[] strings = {"Team A 2-3 Team B", "Team A  Team B"};

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

        for (String string : strings) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
            if(matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println("Home team: " + matcher.group(1));
                if(matcher.group(2) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Home goal: " + matcher.group(2));
                    System.out.println("Away goal: " + matcher.group(3));
                }
                System.out.println("Away team: " + matcher.group(4));
                System.out.println("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Explanation

- `([\w ]*?)` Capture any character in the set (word characters or space) any number of times, but as few as possible, into capture group 1
- `\s+` Match one or more whitespace characters
- `(?:(\d+)-(\d+))?` Match the following zero or one time

  - `(\d+)` Capture one or more digits into capture group 2
  - `-` Match the hyphen character `-` literally
  - `(\d+)` Capture one or more digits into capture group 3
- `\s+` Match one or more whitespace characters
- `([\w ]*)` Capture any character in the set (word characters or space) any number of times into capture group 4

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and the useful tool. What can I do to add each group into the variables I've declared? In particular, 2 strings and 2 integers (1 each for home and away team).

Comment: @H.T see my most recent edit (I changed the code under **Usage**). It better shows how to work with my solution.

Answer (score -1):

If the scores in the middle of the string may not be present, you can modify your expression to indicate so:

```
    boolean b = Pattern.matches(" ((\\d+)-(\\d+))? ", input);
    ...
    String[] teamNames = input.split(" ((\\d+)-(\\d+))? ");
```